# maximum possible probability

Tags: probability

75% of the customers of ACME Mutual Insurance have auto insurance, and 40% have homeowners
insurance. What is the maximum possible probability that a randomly selected customer with auto
insurance does not have homeowners insurance?

i did the approach P(a)-P(A and B) but the answer is .8 i dont know how

Comment: answer is .8, i dont know how

Comment: i have pasted the exact question ad don't know how to get to the answer

Comment: Hmm it's given that the selected customer has auto insurance.

Comment: This asks for conditional probability. If $A$ is the set of customers with auto insurance and $B$ those with home insurance, we need maximum value of $P(B^c|A)$. Note that minimum value of $P(A\cap B)$ is $0.15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A be the set that have auto insurance  and B the set that have homeowners insurance and U denote universal set.
You want to maximize, 
$$P(B^c|A)$$
$$P(B^c|A)= \frac{P(B^c \cap A)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B^c|A)= \frac{P(A\setminus A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B^c|A)= \frac{P(A) - P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$
$$P(B^c|A) \leq 1-\frac{0.15}{0.75}$$
$$P(B^c|A) \leq 0.8$$